# Parse a CSV file and insert its content as new lines before the last matching pattern using sed or awk or any unix utils

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I would like to parse a csv file and insert its content as new lines before the last matching pattern (matching pattern ) in another file.

CSV file contents

```
10.200.1.20,255.255.255.0
10.200.1.30,255.255.255.0
```

Second file where the insertion is required:

```
<!-- Example IP list
<IPLIST>
</IPLIST>
Example end -->
<IPLIST>
<ip NODE_ID="100.10.10.10" NETMASK="255.255.255.0"/>
<ip NODE_ID="100.10.10.10" NETMASK="255.255.255.0"/>
</IPLIST>
```

Please help me in how to achieve this

Comment: better start showing your attempts! Also, [edit] the question to show the format properly. You may want to read [ask] for a better experience here : )

Comment: tac a | awk '/<\/IPLIST>/ && !seen {sub(/<\/IPLIST>/,"<\/IPLIST>\n10.200.1.20,255.255.255.0");seen =1} 1' | tac                                   I tried using awk and tac as shown above but my attempts to read from another file in sub function doesnot work.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question showing these valuable attempts. Glad to read you did try something, just make it more clear and I am sure somebody will find the time to check this question.

Answer (score 0):

To handle XML, use a proper XML handling tools. For example, your task can be accomplished by the following [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2) script:

```
open input.xml ;
perl { open $FH, '<', 'file.csv' or die $! } ;
while { $line = <$FH> } {
    $line = normalize-space($line) ; # Remove the final newline.
    $ip := insert element ip append /IPLIST ;
    set $ip/@NODE_ID substring-before($line, ",") ;
    set $ip/@NETMASK substring-after($line, ",") ;
    insert text {"\n"} after $ip ;
}
save :b ;
```